# Where to read global setting in Angular 2 application?

Tags: angular

I have global settings in application, that are stored in local storage.

I need to write service that is launched at ones after loading application to load settings from local storage.

Where to do that?

I can write service and call this in each components, but it is not convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create [resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) and call service one time when your application load

see the example [how to use](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve#how-to-use)

also you can create getter and setter methods so you easily access in every component

for example

```
// import
export class AppConfigService{
  public token: string;
  Constructor(private http: Http){
  }


 get token(): string{
        return this.token;
    }

  getAppConfig(): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.get('apiBaseUrl')
            .toPromise()
            .then(resp => {
               this.token = res.token;
            }).catch(function (err: any): any {
                Observable.throw(err);
            });
    }
}
```

**solution 2**

Put this function into app module

```
export function loadAppConfig(appService: AppConfigService): Function {
    return () => appService.getAppConfig();
}
```

add this into providers

```
providers: [
        AppConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: loadAppConfig,
            deps: [AppConfigService],
            multi: true
        },
]
```

Comment: But I need call this service instantly after hard reloading page by f5

Comment: Can I load this service once at NgMOdule?

Comment: Can I inject(load) this in global provider in NgModel?

Comment: check solution 2. may be help

Comment: Man, I have a lot of components, it is hard to inject this service in each. I try to find way where to initialize service once in one place

Comment: you need to just  write only in app module

Comment: I did this in NgModule: `providers: [
    Init]` but it does not work, I can not see message in `Init` constructor service

Comment: have you import APP_INITIALIZER?

Comment: i think first solution good for you. when you app loaded and redirect on route that time you can call resolver

Comment: I can not see how to import this in NgModulw. it does not call constructor

Comment: it does not call constructor. means? why you need  and where?

Comment: import {NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER} from '@angular/core' just imort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165046/discussion-between-shailesh-ladumor-and-jessie).

Answer (score 1):

You can load settings from the local storage in the constructor of the service. When the service will be loaded first time, settings will be loaded. But be sure that the service will be singleton across application. The usage of your service is shared across your application.

Comment: So, then I need to import this service in each component, also how to provide singleton of service?

Comment: You just need to add it into the providers of the main module - in most cases it is the AppModule, after this injecting it in every component where you want to use it will just return the created instance

Comment: But I need call this service instantly after hard reloading page by f5, is it be loaded?

Comment: Why not. When you refresh it will again create the component and inject the service into it